# Why do I get "Maximum call stack size exceeded" and "TypeError" errors when I click buttons in a jQuery-UI dialog?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I am trying to use a [jQuery-UI dialog](http://jqueryui.com/dialog/#modal-form) to make a "Change Password" form that lets the user of my site submit a new password for his/her account.

Here is the function that creates and opens the dialog:

```
function MakeChangePasswordDialog(userId) {
    var form;

    var dialog = $('#dialog-form').dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        height: 400,
        width: 350,
        modal: false,
        buttons: {
            'OK': ChangePassword(userId, $('#password').val(), $('#confirm_password').val()),
            'Cancel': function() {
                dialog.dialog('close');
            }
        },
        close: function() {
            form.reset();
            allFields.removeClass('ui-state-error');
        }
    });

    // "Change Password" dialog form
    form = dialog.find('form').on('submit', function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        ChangePassword(userId, $('#password').val(), $('#confirm_password').val());
    });

    dialog.dialog('open');
}
```

Here is the function that changes the password:

```
function ChangePassword (userId, newPassword, confirmNewPassword) {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://path/to/my/ajax/endpoint',
        type: 'post',
        data: { userId: userId, newPassword: newPassword, confirmNewPassword: confirmNewPassword },
        success: function (result) {
            if (result.substring(0, 1) == "1") {
                alert('Password changed.');
            } else {
                alert('Password not changed.');
            }
        },            error: function(err){
            console.log('Error changing password: ' + err);
        }
    });
}
```

The dialog displays just fine, but when I click the "OK" button, there is a long pause. After about ten seconds, the following error appears in the Google Chrome developer console:

> Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
>
> at buildParams (jquery.js?cdv=151:8426)
>
> at buildParams (jquery.js?cdv=151:8417)
>
> at buildParams (jquery.js?cdv=151:8411)
>
> ... (previous line repeats 7 times)

After getting this error, I inspected the source code using the debugger, and I saw that the "ChangePassword" function got called once immediately after the dialog was opened. I decided that this was erroneous behavior, so I modified the "MakeChangePasswordDialog" function so that the 'OK' button did not have any parameters passed to it. The modified function looked like the following:

```
function MakeChangePasswordDialog(userId) {
    var form;

    var dialog = $('#dialog-form').dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        height: 400,
        width: 350,
        modal: false,
        buttons: {
            'OK': ChangePassword,
            'Cancel': function() {
                dialog.dialog('close');
            }
        },
        close: function() {
            form.reset();
            allFields.removeClass('ui-state-error');
        }
    });

    // "Change Password" dialog form
    form = dialog.find('form').on('submit', function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        ChangePassword(userId, $('#password').val(), 
        $('#confirm_password').val());
    });

    dialog.dialog('open');
}
```

After doing this, I noticed that there was no long pause after I triggered the function, and no error was generated. The dialog displayed just fine, and I was able to enter a new password and confirmation password. However, after I clicked on the "OK" button, I received a similar error. Here it is:

> Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
>
> at buildParams (jquery.js?cdv=151:1)
>
> at buildParams (jquery.js?cdv=151:8411)
>
> ... (the previous line repeats 8 times)

Also, after inspecting the "ChangePassword" function in the debugger, I noticed something peculiar. This is that, instead of passing the "userId," "$('#password')," and "$('#confirm_password')" variables to the function, the jQuery-UI dialog passed the JavaScript event that was generated when the user clicked the button. This caused the "userId" field to be wrong, and the other two fields to be undefined.

Does anyone have any advice for me?

**UPDATE**

I also have another problem: If I click the "Close" button, I get the following error:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'reset' of undefined

After inspecting the debugger, I found that the "form" element had a length of zero in the "close" function. This means that the jQuery selector that returns this element is returning nothing. Why would this be? Thanks so much in advance, and I can make this a new question if necessary. I just thought it would be more convenient to post it in my existing question, since there are so many questions that get asked on StackOverflow.

I am using jQuery version 3.2.1, jQuery-UI version 1.12.1, and Chrome version 66.

**UPDATE**

Thank you so much everyone. After following your suggestions, it works! The final version of my "MakeChangePasswordDialog" function is this:

```
var dialog;

function MakeChangePasswordDialog (userId) {
    // "Change Password" dialog
    dialog = $('#dialog-form').dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        height: 400,
        width: 350,
        modal: false,
        buttons: {
            'OK': function () { ChangePassword (userId, $('#password').val(), $('#confirm_password').val()) },
            'Cancel': function () {
                dialog .dialog('close');
            }
        }
    });

    dialog .dialog('open');
}
```

Also, for completeness's sake, here is the div that contains the form:

```
<div id="dialog-form" title="Change Password" style="display:none;">
<form id="dialog-form-form">
    <fieldset>
        <label for="password">Password</label>
        <input type="password" name="password" id="password" value="" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all">
        <label for="confirm_password">Confirm Password</label>
        <input type="password" name="confirm_password" id="confirm_password" value="" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all">

        <!-- Allow form submission with keyboard without duplicating the dialog button -->
        <input type="submit" tabindex="-1" style="position:absolute; top:-1000px">
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

Comment: The first thing that jumps out: `'OK': ChangePassword(userId, $('#password').val(), $('#confirm_password').val())` Surely you should have a function wrapped around that. That **calls** `ChangePassword` and assigns its return value to the `OK` property.

Comment: Thank you very much for replying so fast! I'm sorry, but I'm having trouble understanding what you mean by having a function "wrapped around that." How can I "wrap" a function around an object's property?

Comment: Exactly the way you did for `Cancel`, which has a function wrapped around `dialog.dialog('close');`: `'OK': function() { ChangePassword(userId, $('#password').val(), $('#confirm_password').val())}`

Comment: What is the content of the `ChangePassword` function? Looks like you might trigger form submission inside it and that would cause an infinite recursion.